# OS X app icon warping

Tags: xcode, image, macos

So I have set an app icon (see first image) for an OS X application at all requested sizes in Images.xcassets but when I run the application it appears as in the second image. Completely warped and stretched. Not sure what could be going on here or really even what to search for to try to figure out what is going on.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Created a new xcassets and it worked this time. No idea what caused the original issue, though.

Comment: And now it is doing it again after no changes I can discern. Sometimes the app icon does not even show up.